# How do I get the guards on my side

Tags: alternate-reality, dystopia

*Previous question: [How to kill a telepathic, defended Person](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/56258/20143). All rules and effects from previous question/accepted answer still apply.*

It's been 33 Days since what I/My dictatorship dubbed 'The McRib*' incident: A group of 12 Adults and 2 teenagers, wearing tin-foil hats, murdered A unit of the Thought Police. Reports later came in of another 2 being murdered by Various known and unknown rebel groups.

Meanwhile, these groups are trying to persuade guards to join their ranks, and also to get a decent headquarters, inside info.... Valuable information. However, they have the following issues:

- They can't just walk up and ask, for what I hope are obvious reasons.
- The guards are treated really well to *try* to prevent conversion.
- Tin-foil hats cannot be used. It is also advised against using anything physical (but they still have anything they can do on win95. Yes, windows 95. Not 2095, I mean 1995)

How can they overcome this?

*This is why we don't mix food and writing, kids.

Comment: Dan, an interesting scenario but getting into the intentions of characters and what drives them to certain actions is essentially impossible to objectively define in an answer.  That is part of writing the story.

Comment: @James Ah. Yes. I do see what you mean. Consider the guards common, and as a 'could be' situation. The whole point of this story is to prove that complete strangers can still work together, and that they did so both in the story, and making the story. The whole thing is symbolistic of collaboration. It's as much my story as it is anyone's who's has given input to its story. It's like art, but you can point at it and say "I did that."

Answer (score 1):

It sure would have been nice to either kidnap a telepath, or raise one yourself. Keep a tinfoil hat on your telepath's head to prevent the thought police from finding him/her.  Give your telepath a great sales pitch as to why the government is evil and needs to be overthrown. Then, your telepath could handle the guard(s) by saying exactly the right things to convince them, based on the guard's secret thoughts. Or your telepath could read the guards' thoughts to find out if the guards knew of any loopholes in the security.